# How can I add new category in a categorical variables after a qcut?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a categorical variable and I want to create a new category for a specific value of other variable

I have a dataframe with a variable `Score` that takes values from 0-100. I did deciles out of it but I want to create a new category for a specific value

```
df['Score_pr']=pd.qcut(df['Score'] ,10,duplicates='drop')

df.loc[X_n['Score']==1,'Score_pr']='0'
```

I expected a new categroy `0` for all cases that had `Score=1`
but I had this message:

> Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the
>   categories first

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: sorry, I'll do it in 3 diferent comments as I'm not sure how to do it in a unique comment.. :(

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]*100})

Comment: df['Score_pr']=pd.qcut(df['Score'] ,10,duplicates='drop')

Comment: df.loc[df['Score']==1,'Score_pr']='0'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error litterally says that you need to set the category before assigning something to it. So, create it. Here is a link to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html#pandas.Series.cat.add_categories).

Since you didn't provide an output, I don't know if that's what you were looking for, but I think this is it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [1, 2, 3,4,5,6]*100})
print(df.head())
#      Score
# 0      1
# 1      2
# 2      3
# 3      4
# 4      5
df['Score_pr'] = pd.qcut(df['Score'] , 10, duplicates='drop')
print(df.head())
#      Score      Score_pr
# 0      1  (0.999, 2.0]
# 1      2  (0.999, 2.0]
# 2      3    (2.0, 3.0]
# 3      4    (3.5, 4.0]
# 4      5    (4.0, 5.0]
df['Score_pr'] = df['Score_pr'].cat.add_categories('0')
df.loc[df['Score']==1,'Score_pr']='0'
print(df.head())
#      Score      Score_pr
# 0      1             0
# 1      2  (0.999, 2.0]
# 2      3    (2.0, 3.0]
# 3      4    (3.5, 4.0]
# 4      5    (4.0, 5.0]
```

And if you want to reorder so that the '0' comes as the first category...

```
cat = df['Score_pr'].cat.categories.tolist()
cat = cat[:-1]
cat.insert(0, '0')
series = pd.Series(cat)
df['Score_pr'] = df['Score_pr'].cat.reorder_categories(series)
```

Comment: Yes! but I have a little problem now...I want that new category to be the first one and not the last one...

Comment: This is ... if I write

Comment: df['Score_pr'].value_counts().sort_index()

Comment: I have this results:

Comment: (0.999, 2.0]    100
(2.0, 3.0]      100
(3.0, 3.5]        0
(3.5, 4.0]      100
(4.0, 5.0]      100
(5.0, 6.0]      100
0               100

Comment: but I want the new category to be the first one to be shown... is that possible? thanks again!

Comment: @Marina Well, you could do `df['Score_pr'].cat.categories` to get a series of all the categories. Then, you can reorder them as you please. In fact, here I think you should get the np.array of the series and simply insert the last element as the first of the list. Then, convert this back to a Series and use `df['Score_pr'].cat.reorder_categories(your New order)` :)

Comment: I tryed! but I have a new mistake: "ValueError: items in new_categories are not the same as in old categories"

Comment: this is what I'm writing:  > df['Score_pr'].cat.reorder_categories(['0','(0.999, 2.0]', '(2.0, 3.0]','(3.0, 3.5]','(3.5, 4.0]','(4.0, 5.0]','(5.0, 6.0]'], inplace=True)

Comment: @Marina I will check that when I will be behind a computer but you do not use a Series when you should use one. You're using a list right now

Comment: @Marina If the answer suits you and worked, I invite you to upvote and check it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Marina I updated my answer, it should work ;) don't forget the upvote and to accept if that suits you

Answer (score 0):

At least with modern `pandas` versions, ordering the new value first can be done in one (long) line:

```
# Add '0' as a category value:
df['Score_pr'] = df['Score_pr'].cat.add_categories('0')
# Order it before the other values:
df['Score_pr'] = df['Score_pr'].cat.reorder_categories(np.roll(df['Score_pr'].cat.categories, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would you extend your solution with dataframe example existing in the above answer? It seems the 2nd script doesn't apply to reorder correctly when I checked with a slightly manipulated dataframe example `df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [1, 2,3,1,4,5,6]*100})`.

Comment: What's the problem @Mario? The category becomes `['0' < (0.999, 2.0] < (2.0, 3.0] < (3.0, 4.0] < (4.0, 5.0] < (5.0, 6.0]]` as expected.

Comment: If you check the output of `df.head()` using your solution [here](https://i.imgur.com/xc9vLpJ.jpg), the first row is not as expected in the absence of `df.loc[df['Score']==1,'Score_pr']='0'` as I commented in the screenshot.

Comment: @Mario LGMT, what do you expect?

Comment: OP asked *"I expected a new category `0` for all cases that had `Score=1`"* so the final output should be like the last `print(df.head())` has been shown in the above-accepted answer. Please see this [here](https://i.imgur.com/EItSuYb.jpg).

Comment: @Mario Sure, then just do `df.loc[df['Score'] == 1, 'Score_pr'] = '0'` after adding/moving the category, like they already did.